# Install Caliburn.Micro add-on in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I want to install the Caliburn.Micro extension in Visual Studio 2019. When I went to the installer manager, I cannot find it. I did not find installing information on the internet. Please, could you help me to do that?

Comment: Are you talking about *Visual Studio extensions* or *nuget packages*? Are you sure you want *caliber.micro* and not [Caliburn.Mirco](https://caliburnmicro.com/)?

Comment: you're right, it is Caliburn.Mirco.

Comment: Did this solve your problem?

Comment: no, it is just a misspelling in the question, I tried with Caliburn.Mirco and it doesn't exist in packages list..

Comment: If using the *nuget package manager* in visual studio, make sure you have selected the tab "Browse" and not for example "Installed". Also check if you have selected "All" in the *Package source* drop down.

Comment: Are you trying to install Vs Extensions or Nuget Package ?

Comment: I right clik preferences -> manage packages NuGet.. -> browse and in the search box I wrote  Calibrun but there is no shuch add-on